# First and Second Fundamental Form - Direction of Parametrisation

Tags: differential-geometry

I just have a small doubt.  Do the First and Second Fundamental forms depend on the direction of parametrisation?  I know that when completely different parametrisations are used, the fundamental forms also change.  However, does direction play any role?

Answer (score 1):

For completely different parametrizations the forms are completely different.

It is not clear what direction and angles you refer to, the please clarify with a simple example.

If first Fundamental Form only is given, then all surfaces are same upto *Bending* by *isometry*. The directions vary a lot as the normal curvature at any point is arbitrarily variable but in relation to its neighborhood.

But when both the fundamental forms are given, a rigid surface is completely defined with arbitrary rotation and translations (euclidean motions) in 3D. Ther can be no spatial change relatively between any two patches of the surface.